# How do you get the selected character position in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, character-encoding, jtextarea

Here is a challenging question!

Let me first tell you my scenario how am i implementing a solution to a problem.

I am reading a log file and displaying it on the JTextArea. Log file is cp037 character coded. I was reading each file as a byte stream or byte array from the log file & displaying it. Anyways, i managed to display the text properly in JTextArea by cp037 character coding.

Now, User may select a set of characters in the JTextArea. All i want is the position of first character of the user's selected text, from a nearest special character '+'(its character code in cp037 is 4E), which is prior to the selected text. This character may occur at several places in the JTextArea.

In simple sentence, i want the first character location(of user selected text) from nearset '+' which should be occuring prior to the user's selected text.

PS: cp037 is a type of character encoding  scheme which is created by IBM & used for IBM Mainframes.

Please fell free to ask me if the question is not clear...:->

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JTextComponent](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html) has a method

```
public int getSelectionStart()
```

Returns the selected text's start position. Return 0 for an empty document, or the value of dot if no selection.

```
public String getSelectedText()
```

Returns the selected text contained in this TextComponent. If the selection is null or the document empty, returns null.

Answer (score 2):

The two methods `getSelectionEnd()`, `getSelectionStart()` of [`JTextComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html) will help you.

```
String firstSelectedChar;
String text = textArea.getText();
int selectionStart = textArea.getSelectionStart();
firstSelectedChar = text.substring(selectionStart, selectionStart + 1);
```

That may be similar to what you need.